# Control relay from PIC18 microchip

Tags: microchip, mplab, pic18

I have a PIC18F24K20 microchip, and wants to control a relay. It works fine from my RasPI over GPIO - but i cant get it working trough my microchip.

My test program is this:

```
#include <xc.h>

#define R1          LATBbits.LATB0
#define R1_TRIS     TRISBbits.RB0

#define R2          LATBbits.LATB1
#define R2_TRIS     TRISBbits.RB1

void main(void) {

    R1_TRIS = 0;
    R2_TRIS = 0;

    R1 = 1;
    R2 = 0;

    return;
}
```

What is im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. replace the `return;`

with:

```
while(1)
{
   ClrWdt();
}
```

2. according datasheet,RB0 and RB1 have several modules connected to these pins,so you should verify they are turned off:
   Analog,
   ECCP,
   Comparator.
   BTW why using two pins in order to control one relay?

3.you may need add driver in order to operat the relay.

according datasheet, add following initialization code:

```
CCP1CON=0;
CCP2CON=0;
ADCON0=0;
CM1CON0=0;
CM2CON0=0;
```

also PBADEN bit at configuration bit should be zero.

Comment: Im just using two pins to test. No driver is needed, it just need a signal input to turn on. But how can i disable the other functions on the pins?

Comment: I updated my answer.please try add initialization code.

Answer (score 0):

The main function should never return in the embedded PIC processors. In some implementations, it would cause a software reset which would cause your pins to go back to high impedance mode. Try adding while (1); at the end of your main.

Comment: I changed my code to:

void main(void) {
    
    R1_TRIS = 0;
    R2_TRIS = 0;

    R1 = 0;
    R2 = 1;
        
    while(1){
    
        // Keep program running
                
    }
    
}

But it still not turn on the relay on either RB1 or RB0

Answer (score 0):

Check if the used pins have other functions. The typical gotcha is that the pins double as analog pins and are enable by default.

Disable them by looking up which AN pin they correspond to in the datasheet and disable them with code like

```
  ANSEL.ANS0 = 0;  
  ANSEL.ANS1 = 0;
```

If you enable watchdog functionality you also might want to add a

```
  ClrWdt();
```

to the main WHILE loop (which was a good suggestion from Mathieu)

Comment: My XC8 compiler cant build when adds the ANSEL code you provided?

Comment: Check datasheet if the pins you use have analog functionality.